# Dart - Instantiate Generic Type by Mapping Constructors

Tags: dart, flutter

You cannot instantiate a generic type in Dart and you cannot use mirrors in Flutter. However, you *can* map types to their constructors in a closure.

This could be useful for something like JSON serialization when working with handwritten classes, especially if the data source returns the same data shape in many forms, i.e `Future<T>` or `Stream<T>`.

Question: Is this a valid pattern and are there any potential drawbacks? Better alternatives?

```dart
class Dog{}
class Cat{}

Map models = {
    Dog: () => Dog(),
    Cat: () => Cat()
};

class Database<T> {
  T data;
  Database() {
    data = models[T](); // <-- this feels a bit weird, but works
  }
}

void main() {

  Database<Cat> cat = Database();
  print(cat.data is Cat);

}
```

Comment: I like it.  An obvious drawback is that it that `Database<T>` works only with specific types, and you need to keep the corresponding `Map<Type, dynamic Function()>` updated, but I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Database called 'Cat'? And which data tables contains database ''cat?